# Setting string value to class when using TextFormField -> onSaved

Tags: flutter

I'm attempting to set a string value to a class. This String is a child's name, I have a function with saves several data from a product into firebase, the data that is saved is acquired from firebase, although I have 1 data (child's name) with needs to be saved with the firebase orders. I attempted to set a constructor that sets the child's Name, but on firebase I got null.
[image]

How I attempted to set the data:

```
import 'package:brasil_fields/brasil_fields.dart';
import 'package:cpf_cnpj_validator/cpf_validator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/order.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/orders_manager.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/user_manager.dart';
import 'package:mask_text_input_formatter/mask_text_input_formatter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ChildCustomName extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 3,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Nome Pesonalizado:',
              style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(
                  textStyle:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: TextFormField(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'João Pedro',
                      isDense: true,
                      border: InputBorder.none),
                  validator: (nome) {
                    if (nome!.isEmpty) return 'Inválido';
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (name) {
                    print(name);
                    Order(name);
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When printing the name, I get the right name
This is the class:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/address.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/cart_manager.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/cart_product.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/user_manager.dart';

enum Status { canceled, preparing, transporting, delivered }

class Order {
  Order(this.childName);

  Order.fromCartManager(CartManager cartManager) {
    items = List.from(cartManager.items);
    price = cartManager.totalPrice;
    userId = cartManager.user!.id;
    address = cartManager.address;
    status = Status.preparing;
  }

  Order.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    orderId = doc.documentID;

    items = (doc.data['items'] as List<dynamic>).map((e) {
      return CartProduct.fromMap(e as Map<String, dynamic>);
    }).toList();

    price = doc.data['price'] as num;
    userId = doc.data['user'] as String;
    address = Address.fromMap(doc.data['address'] as Map<String, dynamic>);
    date = doc.data['date'] as Timestamp;

    status = Status.values[doc.data['status'] as int];
  }

  final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

  DocumentReference get firestoreRef =>
      firestore.collection('orders').document(orderId);

  void updateFromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    status = Status.values[doc.data['status'] as int];
  }

  Future<void> save() async {
    firestore.collection('orders').document(orderId).setData({
      'items': items!.map((e) => e.toOrderItemMap()).toList(),
      'price': price,
      'user': userId,
      'address': address!.toMap(),
      'status': status!.index,
      'date': Timestamp.now(),
      'childName': childName
    });
  }

  Function()? get back {
    return status!.index >= Status.transporting.index
        ? () {
            status = Status.values[status!.index - 1];
            firestoreRef.updateData({'status': status!.index});
          }
        : null;
  }

  Function()? get advance {
    return status!.index <= Status.transporting.index
        ? () {
            status = Status.values[status!.index + 1];
            firestoreRef.updateData({'status': status!.index});
          }
        : null;
  }

  void cancel() {
    status = Status.canceled;
    firestoreRef.updateData({'status': status!.index});
  }

  String? orderId;

  String get formattedId => '#${orderId!.padLeft(6, '0')}';

  List<CartProduct>? items;
  num? price;

  String? userId;

  Address? address;

  Timestamp? date;

  String? childName;

  Status? status;

  String get statusText => getStatusText(status!);

  static String getStatusText(Status status) {
    switch (status) {
      case Status.canceled:
        return 'Cancelado';
      case Status.preparing:
        return 'Em preparação';
      case Status.transporting:
        return 'Em transporte';
      case Status.delivered:
        return 'Entregue';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Order{firestore: $firestore, orderId: $orderId, items: $items, price: $price, userId: $userId, address: $address, date: $date}';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a solution with I believe works fine.

```
class Order{

statis String? childName;

}
```

OnSaved:

```
onSaved: (name) {
                    Order.childName = name;
                  }),
```